# Give focus to returned element in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a slideshow lightbox which gets activated when a particular thumbnail image gets focus and 'Ente'r is pressed. When I close the lightbox, focus is returned to the same thumbnail image, so the tabbing order is not disturbed.
I'm using a global variable for it and it works great but I want to try not to use a global variable. This the working code:

```
let focusedImgBeforeSlideshow

function openSlideshow () {

  *code which opens the slideshow*

  focusedImgBeforeSlideshow = document.activeElement
}


function closeSlideshow () {
  *code which closes the slideshow*

  focusedImgBeforeSlideshow.focus()
}
```

I have tried wrapping `focusedImgBeforeSlideshow` in a function and calling it in `openSlideshow()` like this:

```
function focusedImg () {
  const focusedImgBeforeSlideshow = document.activeElement
  return focusedImgBeforeSlideshow
}

function openSlideshow () {
  focusedImg()
}
```

... and it works but the problem is, I can't return the focus when I close the slideshow.
I have tried this:

```
function closeSlideshow () {
  focusedImg().focus()
}
```

... but this is nonsense, obviously.
Another way I've tried was this:

```
function focusedImg () {
  const focusedImgBeforeSlideshow
  return focusedImgBeforeSlideshow
}

function openSlideshow () {
  let focused = focusedImg ()

  focused = document.activeElement
  
  return focused
}
```

... but then again the problem starts when I close the slideshow.

```
function closeSlideshow () {
  let returnedFocus = openSlideshow ()

  returnedFocus.focused.focus()
}
```

How can I return focus without using a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to declare a global variable, you can wrap your code into a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) using `exports` keyword.

If you are using okd javascript (Ecmascript 5), you can declare a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to wrap your code into a function and prevent exposing the `focusedImgBeforeSlideshow` variable.

```
(function() {
  var focusedImgBeforeSlideshow

  window.openSlideshow = function () {
    focusedImgBeforeSlideshow = document.activeElement

    *code which opens the slideshow*
  }

  window.closeSlideshow = function () {
    *code which closes the slideshow*

    focusedImgBeforeSlideshow.focus()
  }

})()
```